# Can't remove watermark from layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How would I remove the watermark from the image below? I tried with the lasso tool and got a message that this layer cannot be edited directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround

- Try selecting the target pixels (where there is formatting)
- Perform a free transform
- Then refill and blend the pixels